# Unixのパイプラインで透過的にふるまうRubyのスクリプトを作るには？

Tags: ruby

こんにちは。標準ストリームについての質問です。
Unixのパイプラインで使用して、透過的に使うツールを作りたいと考えています。(透過的という用語をこの文脈で使っていいのかどうかわかりませんが、具体的には `tee` のようなものを想定しています。)

下記のようなスクリプト `pass.rb` を作成したとして

```rb
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

lines = readlines.map(&:chomp)

# do something useful...
#   
# end

puts lines
```

`chmod +x pass.rb`

この `pass.rb` はパイプの中間に挟んだ時に

```sh
hoge | ./pass.rb | fuga
```

```sh
hoge | fuga
```

fugaに渡される入力データは常に同じになるでしょうか？

もし同等にならない場合は、どのような例で問題が発生するのか、
どうすれば同等にできるのかを教えて頂けると助かります。

よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: `pass.rb` の中で受け取ったデータを何かしら加工して出力するのであれば、`fuga` に渡るデータは当然 (`pass.rb` を挟まない場合と比較して) データは変わるのではないでしょうか？

Comment: `lines` は参照するだけで加工はせず直接 `puts` に渡すつもりです

Comment: Ruby については詳しくないので直接の回答はできませんが、基本的には標準入出力を介してやり取りするようにスクリプトを組めば良いだけのはずです。 / まずは実際に試してみて、何か問題が出るようであればその時点で質問してみると、具体的な回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: ほとんどのケースで、これで大丈夫だと思うのですが、何か変な文字が入ると飛ぶよ、みたいな特殊なケースがないか探しています…

Comment: 入力ファイルの最後が改行コードではない場合、例えば `printf 'Hello' | wc -c` は `5` になりますが、`printf 'Hello' | ./pass.rb | wc -c` は `6` になってしまいます。

Comment: なるほど。たしかに！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chomp` しているので、入力されたデータの改行コードが変わる可能性があります。

たとえば改行コードのデフォルトが LF の環境において改行コードが CRLF の入力を食わせると、出力の改行コードが LF になってしまいます。

```sh
% cat foo.txt | od -c
0000000    a   a   a  \r  \n                                            
0000005
% cat foo.txt | ./pass.rb | od -c
0000000    a   a   a  \n                                                
0000004
```

パイプからテキスト以外のデータが流れてくる可能性も考えると、入出力部分ではバイナリデータとして読み書きし、"do something useful" 部分で必要に応じてテキストデータに変換するのが良さそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かに。要注意ですね…

Answer (score 2):

> パイプの中間に pass.rb を挟んだ時に
> fugaに渡される入力データは常に同じになるでしょうか？
> もし同等にならない場合は、どのような例で問題が発生するのか

nekketsuuuさんの回答のとおり、NGとなるケースがあるようです。

> どうすれば同等にできるのかを教えて頂けると助かります。

rubyに詳しくないので、見当違いかもしれませんが、あらゆるケースを想定するなら、バイナリとして読み込み、バイナリとして書き込む方法しか思いつきません。

---

次の方法を使えば、お望みのことが実現できると思います。かなり邪道です。
標準エラー出力を本来とは異なる用途で使っているので、実務に使うのは危険です。
エラーメッセージがスクリプトに処理されたり、表示されなくなったりするからです。
なお、teeコマンドとbashのcoprocを使っています。

やり方は以下のとおりです。
1)coprocでスクリプトを起動します。※例えば`pass.rb`
2)teeを使って標準入力を標準エラー出力デバイスファイルに流します。
3)teeの標準出力はcoprocで起動したスクリプトの標準入力に書き込みます。
4)標準エラー出力を標準出力に戻します。

以下のように実行します。スクリプトはpeep.shとしています。

```
hoge | ./peep.sh スクリプト | fuga
```

peep.shの内容

```sh
#!/bin/bash
prc=$1
coproc cprc { ${prc}; }
{
    tee -p /dev/stderr >&${cprc[1]}

} 2>&1
```

Comment: なるほど。勉強になります。ただ、今回は標準エラー出力は他のことに使いたいので、バイナリでも読み込み書き込みに成功するようにテストするのみにしたいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

次のようにしました。

```rb
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

while = Kernel.gets(nil)
  input.freeze # 変更されないようにする

  # 処理

  print input
end
```